# Display Database Entities within a specific time frame

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I want to display content from the database with dates up to 2hours ahead of time.

Example:

```
2018-11-09 20:00:00.000000
2018-11-08 19:00:00.000000
2018-11-06 19:00:00.000000
2018-11-06 18:00:00.000000
```

Lets say the time and date is
Nov 6th at 6pm. I want the bottom two entries to be displayed and the two future dates to not show until the current time is within 2hours of that time.

My code is as follows:

```
$cT = strtotime($row3['MissionTime']) - strtotime("now");
                         if($cT <= strtotime('-2 hours')) {
                                 echo $row3['MissionTime']."<br>";
                            }
```

I've tried several different ways but I can't seem to get this to work right. Help and tips?

Comment: What is your actual problem - does it show too few / too many / no dates? There must be some sort of "while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($db_res)){ ... " loop that is not included here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is that `strtotime` returns a number of seconds since the unix epoch. When you subtract two results of `strtotime` you will get a number of seconds difference which is as you expect. However you cannot compare that value to `strtotime('-2 hours')` as the output of that will be the timestamp for 2 hours before now (which right now is 1541539906), so the test will always pass. You should just compare it to 7200 instead (I'm pretty sure based on your question description that +7200 is more appropriate than -7200). so change

```
if($cT <= strtotime('-2 hours')) {
```

to

```
if($cT <= 7200) {
```

Note that it is almost certainly better to do this in your query. Try adding a condition on your time column as something like

```
WHERE MissionTime <= NOW() + INTERVAL 2 HOUR
```

And then you won't need to check in the PHP at all.

Comment: Good point about fixing it in the query: why have your database retrieve those records if you're going to exclude them later anyway?

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime()` returns a timestamp in seconds. Subtracting two timestamps gives you a difference between those two timestamps, in seconds.

So if `strtotime($row3['MissionTime'])` is a timestamp that's 1.5 hours in the future, and you subtract `strtotime("now")` from it, you end up with a difference of `5400` seconds (60 seconds * 60 minutes * 1.5 hours).

`strtotime('-2 hours')` gives you the timestamp for 2 hours ago, which is currently somewhere around 1.5 billion. This is not very useful for your situation.

Here are two ways to modify your code:

```
$cT = strtotime($row3['MissionTime']) - strtotime("now");
if($cT <= 7200) {
    echo $row3['MissionTime']."<br>";
}
```

If the difference between `$row['MissionTime']` and `now` is less than `7200` seconds (60 seconds * 60 minutes * two hours), `$row3['MissionTime']` is either in the past or it's within the next two hours.

Alternatively:

```
if(strtotime($row3['MissionTime']) <= strtotime('+2 hours')) {
    echo $row3['MissionTime']."<br>";
}
```

Basically the same, but perhaps more readable if you're not planning to use `$cT` for anything else. This simply checks if `$row3['MissionTime']` is earlier than whatever time it will be in `+2 hours`.